# How to keep a global counter going through if statements?

Tags: php

I am currently trying to parse through a large PHP array of data and write every 10,000 contacts to a separate XML file. I have figured out a way to do this successfully, but for some reason my global counter `$i` is not staying consistent through some of my if statements. Here is the code that is nested within my `while($row=oci_fetch_array($array)` statment and after I did some validation to the data. I also set a variable `$i=0;` directly before this while statment.

```
global $i;

if ($i<10001) {
    global $file1;
    fwrite($file1, '<contact contactID="'.$row["UNIQUE ID"].'" action="AddOrModify">
        <contactField name="LastName">'.$row["LAST NAME"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="FirstName">'.$row["FIRST NAME"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="MiddleName">'.$row["MIDDLE INITIAL"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="Country">'.$row["COUNTRY"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="Code">'.$row["CODE"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 1"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 1"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 2"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 2"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 3"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 3"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 4"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 4"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 5"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 5"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 6"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 6"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 7"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 7"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 8"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 8"].'</contactField>

        <contactPointList>
            <contactPoint type="Voice">
                <contactPointField name="Label">'.$row["PHONE LABEL 1"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="CountryCode">'.$row["PHONE 1 COUNTRY CODE"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="Number">'.$row["PHONE 1"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="Extension">'.$row["PHONE EXTENSION 1"].'</contactPointField>
            </contactPoint>

            <contactPoint type="Voice">
                <contactPointField name="Label">'.$row["PHONE 2 LABEL"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="CountryCode">'.$row["PHONE 2 COUNTRY CODE"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="Number">'.$row["PHONE 2"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="Extension">'.$row["PHONE EXTENSION 2"].'</contactPointField>
            </contactPoint>

            <contactPoint type="Email">
                <contactPointField name="Label">'.$row["EMAIL LABEL 1"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="Address">'.$row["EMAIL 1"].'</contactPointField>
            </contactPoint>
        </contactPointList>
    </contact>');

    $i++;
}

if ($i>10000 and $i<20001) {
    global $file2;
    fwrite($file2,'<contact contactID="'.$row["UNIQUE ID"].'" action="AddOrModify">
        <contactField name="LastName">'.$row["LAST NAME"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="FirstName">'.$row["FIRST NAME"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="MiddleName">'.$row["MIDDLE INITIAL"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="Country">'.$row["COUNTRY"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="Code">'.$row["CODE"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 1"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 1"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 2"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 2"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 3"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 3"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 4"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 4"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 5"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 5"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 6"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 6"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 7"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 7"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 8"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 8"].'</contactField>

        <contactPointList>
            <contactPoint type="Voice">
                <contactPointField name="Label">'.$row["PHONE LABEL 1"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="CountryCode">'.$row["PHONE 1 COUNTRY CODE"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="Number">'.$row["PHONE 1"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="Extension">'.$row["PHONE EXTENSION 1"].'</contactPointField>
            </contactPoint>

            <contactPoint type="Voice">
                <contactPointField name="Label">'.$row["PHONE 2 LABEL"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="CountryCode">'.$row["PHONE 2 COUNTRY CODE"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="Number">'.$row["PHONE 2"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="Extension">'.$row["PHONE EXTENSION 2"].'</contactPointField>
            </contactPoint>

            <contactPoint type="Email">
                <contactPointField name="Label">'.$row["EMAIL LABEL 1"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="Address">'.$row["EMAIL 1"].'</contactPointField>
            </contactPoint>
        </contactPointList>
    </contact>');

    $i++;
}

if ($i>20000 and $i<30001) {
    global $file3;

    fwrite($file3, '<contact contactID="'.$row["UNIQUE ID"].'" action="AddOrModify">
        <contactField name="LastName">'.$row["LAST NAME"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="FirstName">'.$row["FIRST NAME"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="MiddleName">'.$row["MIDDLE INITIAL"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="Country">'.$row["COUNTRY"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="Code">'.$row["CODE"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 1"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 1"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 2"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 2"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 3"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 3"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 4"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 4"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 5"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 5"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 6"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 6"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 7"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 7"].'</contactField>
        <contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 8"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 8"].'</contactField>

        <contactPointList>
            <contactPoint type="Voice">
                <contactPointField name="Label">'.$row["PHONE LABEL 1"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="CountryCode">'.$row["PHONE 1 COUNTRY CODE"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="Number">'.$row["PHONE 1"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="Extension">'.$row["PHONE EXTENSION 1"].'</contactPointField>
            </contactPoint>

            <contactPoint type="Voice">
                <contactPointField name="Label">'.$row["PHONE 2 LABEL"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="CountryCode">'.$row["PHONE 2 COUNTRY CODE"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="Number">'.$row["PHONE 2"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="Extension">'.$row["PHONE EXTENSION 2"].'</contactPointField>
            </contactPoint>

            <contactPoint type="Email">
                <contactPointField name="Label">'.$row["EMAIL LABEL 1"].'</contactPointField>
                <contactPointField name="Address">'.$row["EMAIL 1"].'</contactPointField>
            </contactPoint>
        </contactPointList>
    </contact>');

    $i++;
}
```

This seems to work almost perfectly, but the last contact found in $file1 is also appearing as the first contact in `$file2` (and the same goes for `$file2` vs. `$file3`). I have tried messing with the `if ($i>x and $i<y)` statements numerous times, but cannot seem to make it just right. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not write your data to a variable then fwrite() at the end?

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this? I have tried storing this as an array, but working with Oracle arrays within PHP seems to give me trouble. I also don't know how I would be able to parse through it by contact and fwrite() it properly.

Comment: Your `$row` column names don't look like valid column names. What exactly is your data source?

Comment: It is being pulled from an Oracle database using an external query. Many of the rows are being pulled using derived names as well.

Comment: All of the above code works just fine though. The only issue is that the $i count doesnt seem to be staying consistent. It seems like some values are appear for being both <10001 and >10000 which shouldnt be

Comment: Why would you not use elseif with <= and >= operators?

Answer (score 0):

After you do `$i++` when `$i = 1000` at the end of the condition body next condition is becoming true. Use `else if () {}` for consecutive conditions or incerement iteration counter once - after all of if statements (at the end of while loop block).

Also it looks like only filenames depend on iteration counter - there's no need to repeat the entire contact body if it stays the same. Like this for example:

```
$files = ['filename1.xml', 'filename2.xml',...];
$i = 0;
while (...) {
    $file_index = intval($i / 1000);
    if (!isset($files[$file_index])) { break; }
    //to be sure all data is written (no break) you need to define more files or assign names with variable: $filename = 'file_' . $file_index;
    $filename = $files[$file_index];
    fwrite($filename, '...');
    $i++;
}
```

if you need to know when file change (to add xml header to string?) you could use this condition:

```
if ($i % 1000 == 0) { ... }
```